# Remove method by name from php class (not in runtime)

Tags: php, regex, parsing

## Situation

1. I have a file which contains 2-3 classes. Each class may and may not contain a destructor function `__destruct()`.
2. I am retrieving these classes using composer and have no real control over it, neither I can selectively say 'go on and ignore lines X~Z' where the destructor calls are located, as these lines may slightly change.
3. I need to get rid of all the destructors - or at least prevent them from executing on object destruction, as other part of code which I have no control over jumps into endless destruct loop.

## Approaches I tried and considered:

### Regex

My initial thought was to **write a regex**, that would match all these functions and removed them (best effort regex, I am sure there would be corner cases for which the regex would not work), but eventually, after remembering various questions about using regexes inappropriately, I reconsidered - not mentioning the fact, that coming up with working regex seems to be a problem for me as well.

### Curly brackets block used for nested scope in C

I have some background in C, so for a second I thought I could just match all the lines with `function __destruct()`, verify there is no `{` on the same line and comment the definition out, so I would get something like this:

```
# function __destruct()
{
echo "initiating destructor function";
$this->callToSomething();
}
```

Which I thought would not execute (or at very least - would not execute on object destruction, which is why I need to comment this out). But PHP does not allow this syntax and I can not do that. Maybe it allows for some other syntax which would achieve the same results?

### Parsing, Reflection? ...?

I do not really want to write myself a PHP parser of its own for this task, but if that is what it will take, I will do it. But since there is already a Reflection class in PHP, maybe there would be a way to load class into the memory, remove the destructors in runtime and then overwrite class definition on disk?

Comment: Other options... fork the package and create your own version without `__destruct`

Comment: Work with the class definition on disk, e.g. awk/sed to remove the `__destruct()` code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I could probably fork it, but in that moment I'll have to manually update the library when new version is released (which I don't want to). Awk/sed would be an option if I could guarantee that code will always run on Linux (which I have no control over).

Comment: To the person who voted to close as too broad - I am asking for a PHP way of removing destructors from file on disc and providing directions which I tried (as is recommended in How to Ask). Care to elaborate on how should I make this more non-broad? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you cannot use a regex here. Sure, you need a more advanced pattern. 
But you should be never forced to touch it.

Here is a pattern that finds `__destruct()` blocks:

```
function\s+__destruct\s*\(\s*\)\s*({(?>[^{}\\]++|\\.|(?1))*+})
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xrsoMM/2)

All you need to do is to load the files in question, run

```
$re = '/function\s+__destruct\s*\(\s*\)\s*({(?>[^{}\\\\]++|\\\\.|(?1))*+})/s';
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

And save the files back to disk. C'est ça.